# Excel clear cells based on contents of a list in another sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, cell

I have an excel Sheet1 of a thousand of rows and 20 columns from A1 to T1. Each cell in that range has some data in it, usually one or two words.
In Sheet2, A1 column I have a list of data of 1000 values.

I am working on VBA script to find words from Sheet2 list in Sheet1 and clear the values of the cells of the found ones.

I now have a VBA script that works only on A1 column of Sheet1 and it deletes the rows only. Here's the script:

```
Sub DeleteEmails() 
Dim rList As Range 
Dim rCrit As Range 

With Worksheets("Sheet1") 
    .Range("A1").Insert shift:=xlDown: .Range("A1").Value = "Temp Header" 
    Set rList = .Range("A1", .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) 
End With 
With Worksheets("Sheet2") 
    .Range("A1").Insert shift:=xlDown: .Range("A1").Value = "Temp Header" 
    Set rCrit = .Range("A1", .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) 
End With 

rList.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=rCrit, Unique:=False 
rList.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete shift:=xlUp 
Worksheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData 

rList(1).Delete shift:=xlUp: rCrit(1).Delete shift:=xlUp 

Set rList = Nothing: Set rCrit = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Could anyone help me? I need the values cleared, not rows deleted, and this should work on all columns of Sheet1, not just A1.

Comment: Use `.Find` See this link http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Comment: @CamSpy based on the value, do you want to clear that cell or delete the entire row or just delete the cell?

Comment: @bonCodigo I want to get the cell cleared, to preserve the sequence of other columns/rows

Comment: @SiddharthRout with what he'd doing, AdvancedFilter is exactly the right tool for the job. I don't understand how people can upvote when find isn't even the issue here.

Comment: @Maverik: Instead of looping every column, you loop the cells in column in Sheet2, and use `.Find` to find the values in Sheet1 and then use `.ClearContents` if the word is found so I am not sure which part you didn't understand :)

Comment: @CamSpy based on your last comment it seems like you still have issues.. However you also have accepted the answer where Marvick has put efforts. So please confirm your conlusion, all good or you need more help?

Comment: @SiddharthRout after talking more about the question, I'd agree that Find probably is more appropriate now as his filtering logic isn't working properly according to him. May be you want to post an answer?

Comment: @Maverik: I could have posted an answer earlier if I wanted to :) I have given OP a link which exactly tells how it can be achieved. If OP is interested, he will at least give it a try and share the code that he tried with the error message(if any) and then I will go ahead and post an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another method using an array by minimizing the traffic between sheet (iteration via range/cells) and code. This code doesn't use any `clear contents`. Simply take the whole range into an array, clean it up and input what you need :) with a click of a button.

- edited as per OP's request: adding comments and changing the code for his desired sheets.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub matchAndClear()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arrKeys As Variant, arrData As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

    '-- here we take keys column from Sheet 1 into a 1D array
    arrKeys = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(1).Range("A2:A11").Value)
    '-- here we take to be cleaned-up-range from Sheet 2 into a 2D array
    arrData = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(2).Range("C2:D6").Value)

    '-- here we iterate through each key in keys array searching it in 
    '-- to-be-cleaned-up array
    For i = LBound(arrKeys) To UBound(arrKeys)
        For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
                '-- when there's a match we clear up that element
                If UCase(Trim(arrData(1, j))) = UCase(Trim(arrKeys(i))) Then
                    arrData(1, j) = " "
                End If
                '-- when there's a match we clear up that element
                If UCase(Trim(arrData(2, j))) = UCase(Trim(arrKeys(i))) Then
                    arrData(2, j) = " "
                End If
        Next j
    Next i

    '-- replace old data with new data in the sheet 2 :)
    Sheets(2).Range("C2").Offset(0, 0).Resize(UBound(arrData, 2), _
    UBound(arrData)) = Application.Transpose(arrData)

End Sub
```

- Please not that you what you really need to set here are the ranges:

  1. Keys range
  2. To-Be-Cleaned up range

Output: (for displaying purpose I am using the same sheet, but you can change the sheet names as you desire.

[image]

Edit based on OP's request for running OP's file:

The reason that it didn't clean all your columns is that in the above sample is only cleaning two columns where as you have 16 columns. So you need to add another `for` loop to iterate through it. Not much performance down, but a little ;) Following is a screenshot after running your the sheet you sent. There is nothing to change except that.

Code:

```
'-- here we iterate through each key in keys array searching it in
    '-- to-be-cleaned-up array
    For i = LBound(arrKeys) To UBound(arrKeys)
        For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
            For k = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
                '-- when there's a match we clear up that element
                If UCase(Trim(arrData(k, j))) = UCase(Trim(arrKeys(i))) Then
                    arrData(k, j) = " "
                End If
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
```

Comment: @Camspy if you are ever interested you may give a try on this as well :) PS: I realized I forgot to post hte code after commenting to you ;)

Comment: Is your code matching entire cell contents? I have explained that in the latest comment to Maverick's answer

Comment: @CamSpy if you want you can define entire cells in the sheet as well. (BTW if  you are going to iterate through entire sheet via cells then it's a huge performance drop... so you are better off doing the iterations like this). This will not have any matching issues that you have pointed out. Exact search key word match ;)

Comment: +1 it is indeed a very nice solution and I'd be happy for you to have the accepted answer for this. Only problem: its too technical! so hope you can stick around until this is perfectly tuned to OPs needs as OP probably won't be able to follow the logic through easily.

Comment: @bonCondigo I'm having troubles editing your script and getting it to work. Could you please edit it so I could have wordlist in sheet2 and a place where to specify the columns in sheet1? Thanks

Comment: CamSpy sure let me get it editted for you. So the only thing you need to edit is : **1.Get key range from sheet 1 2.Get to be cleaned up range in Sheet 2 3.outputing to sheet part** :) @Maverik thanks mate. I didn't post this opposing to your answer. Just thought this would be a little faster ;)

Comment: @bonCodigo we're all here to learn and share our knowledge. I'm happy that I learned a different approach. I had never thought of using Transpose to get an array out of range. That's ingenious :) For that alone, I'd happily have you take the answer credit (yours is superior anyway and best answer should be marked)

Comment: @CamSpy Please see my edit :) it should work. BTW thanks for sending the sheet without Sheet3 data, otherwise it would have been hard to download.. ;) Let me know if you have any doubts, and happy to help. BTW you may add a button to the sheet1 for your convenience.

Comment: @CamSpy well I only give you the code you tried it out and came back with a very valid point, so it's easy to work with you and you are fast learner :D

Comment: @bonCodigo would you mind helping me with a slightly different VBA? Imagine the same XLS file you already saw and worked on. This time, i need some modification that would not clear the cells, but replace found values with other values. So in sheet1 there is a wordlist in A columnt of words to find and in B column with replacement values. Everything else is the same...

Comment: I posted a new question in this thread instead:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361008/excel-find-replace-cell-contents-based-on-contents-of-a-list-in-another-sheet

Comment: Sorry don't remember having a file. What is it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have excel to hand right now so this may not be exactly 100% accurate on formulae name but I believe this line needs to change:

```
rList.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete shift:=xlUp
```

to

```
rList.Offset(1).ClearContents
```

once you've set rList to your desired selection. `Delete` is the reason you're deleting rows and not clearing them. `(1)` is the reason you were doing `A1` only instead of entire range.

**EDIT**

The final code that I tested this with was (includes going over all columns now):

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteEmails()
    Dim rList As Range
    Dim rCrit As Range
    Dim rCells As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("A1").Insert shift:=xlDown
        .Range("A1").Value = "Temp Header"
        Set rCrit = .Range("A1", .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Set rCells = Sheet1.Range("$A$1:$T$1")

    rCells.Insert shift:=xlDown

    Set rCells = rCells.Offset(-1)

    rCells.Value = "Temp Header"

    For i = 1 To rCells.Count
        Set rList = Sheet1.Range(rCells(1, i).address, Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp))

        If rList.Count > 1 Then  'if a column is empty as is in my test case, continue to next column
            rList.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=rCrit, Unique:=False
            rList.Offset(1).ClearContents
            Worksheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData
        End If
    Next i

    rCells.Delete shift:=xlUp
    rCrit(1).Delete shift:=xlUp

    Set rList = Nothing: Set rCrit = Nothing

End Sub
```

PS: may I request that you do not use ':' in vba. Its really hard to notice in vba's default IDE and took me a while to figure why things were happening but not making sense!

Comment: I'm getting Compile Error Syntax Error message when trying to execute the script edited the way you wrote.

Comment: Guess I'll have to grab excel and simulate your sheet :) gimme like half an hour

Comment: @CamSpy should be fixed now. It was the `()` at the end of ClearContents i think that was throwing vba off.

Comment: And I got mixed up earlier with the wrong line because of the elusive ':' that you had used (i thought it was part of named argument and ignored the second line)

Comment: Thank you this one seems to work on the A column of the Sheet1. can you now tell me how to change the code so it works on all A-T columns?

Comment: well you basically need to iterate through columns really in the Set rList = .Range("A1") line. Instead use a for loop on Range("A1:T1") and use that loop cell as argument to Set rList = .Range(cell, .Cells..)

Comment: I made a few tries but results were wrong. Can you please tell me what exactly to replace this line with?:
Set rList = .Range("A1", .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

Comment: @CamSpy I've updated the code with new test code that I used. As long your columns start from A, you'll be fine with this code (you can extend the columns onwards from T if you wish)

Comment: @Maverick, there's something wrong with the updated code: Variable not defined, compile error. Also, "if a column is empty as is in my test case, continue to next column" text is missing another apostrophe at the end?

Comment: no if you copy pasted the WHOLE thing as it is.. it shuoldn't be missing anything because I just copy pasted from my test sheet that has it working. If there's a compile error, then you've missed something or did partial copy paste. `'` means start of a comment - anything that follows it doesn't count in code

Comment: oh wait! its because Option Explicit is defined, and you are using some variable that you haven't `Dim` -ed. The line with error will give you the variable that you're using without defining it first. (by default vba lets use any variable name weather defined or not which can result in typos getting through and having unexpected results)

Comment: @Maverick, i am sorry, i created a new excel document, put the data and your script and everyhing worked well. Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, I just noticed, that the script clears cell values without matching entire cell contents. If in Sheet2 list there is a word "love" and in Sheet1 there is a word "lover", it will be cleared anyways, and it is not correct.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22687/discussion-between-maverik-and-camspy)