# Excel VBA filtering a worksheet based on a range of cells in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

Good evening,

I have been learning how to use VBA for the past few months to automate a number of reports.  This site has been a great help, I have been able to figure out how to do many things, but a solution to this problem still eludes me.  I have a relatively complex macro that has completely automated this particular report with the exception to this step, if I can figure this out, I can achieve full automation of the report.

The system generates a raw data file in a .xls format with new data for the month that must be scrubbed and added into the report template.  Column X contains commodity descriptions, however many of the rows of data have unacceptable commodity descriptions, these rows need to be copied into a separate worksheet and sent to someone else to locate the correct descriptions.  In the main report template, I have created a list of the acceptable commodity descriptions, I want to be able to have the raw data file filter so that any row that has a value in column X that is not in the acceptable list shows and all rows that already contain acceptable descriptions are hidden.

I have tried manipulating the filters, recording the macro, and attempting to manipulate the code but no luck.  Here is what I get when I record the action. some of the items at the beginning of the array are examples of acceptable descriptions (stuff that makes sense), the random stuff at the end are examples of the type of items I want to show, these will need to be researched and manually corrected.

```
Sub hiderows()
    Windows("stop level data.xls").Activate
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AB$1290").AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "Cotton", "Covers", "Displays", "Fabric", "Fasteners", "Fiber", "Fiber Rolls", _
    "Fibers", "Foam", "Foam Rolls", "Frames", "Labels", "Latex", "Lumber", "Machines",_
    "Mattresses", "Pads", "Plastic", "PO #Avi", "PO #P0005557/SO #3203687", _
    "PO #P0005615/SO #3203693", "PO #P0007297/SO#3203828", "Rolls", "Serta", "Springs"_
    , "T000216", "T000247", "T000269", "T000270", "T000278", "T000286", "T000294", _
    "T000296", "Tape", "Thread", "Tick", "Ticking", "Transfer from", "Wood", _
    "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

As a first step, I tried to just get the code above to hide the rows rather than show them by plugging in <> instead of = in a number of different ways but no luck.  What I really want to do is filter the sheet `Windows("Stop level data.xls")` so that if the value in `column X` of a particular row is not equal to a value in `Windows("master template.xlsm").Sheets("lookups").Range("AE2:AE100")`

Thank you in advance for your time, I have spent countless hours fighting with this and am really no closer to a solution.

Comment: `1` Copy the list of unwanted items into a new worksheet. `2` Loop through the list and filter the data based on that list. `3` Copy the filtered data to the output sheet. Here is an example which you can amend and use in your scenario http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s

Comment: Here is another for you to try out, :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302891/excel-clear-cells-based-on-contents-of-a-list-in-another-sheet/14325173#14325173