# Delete sheet if cell content doesn't match a list value

Tags: excel, vba

I've been lurking here for months learning vba to help automate some reports for my job and I've finally come to a point we're I'm utterly stuck and cannot find the answer online.

I have an automatically generated report that has a separate sheet for each person in the company
This will not have a static filename each week so I think i need something like:

```
Dim thiswb as string
thiswb = activeworkbook.name
```

What I'd like to do is, for each sheet in thiswb, unless the name in cell in C4 on matches a name on a list that I have saved in another workbook (this has a static name that will not change "job report"), the sheet is deleted. So in the end I'm left with a workbook with separate sheets for each name on my list.

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using this code, copy your name list from "job report" into the same worksheet.  This macro then cycles through each sheet in a workbook, and uses `FIND` to identify if the name occurs anywhere on the tab called "staffnames".

```vb
Dim focus_SHEET As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
For Each focus_SHEET In Sheets
    focus_SHEET.Select
    Set Rng = Sheets("staffnames").Cells.Find(Range("C4"), LookIn:=xlValues)

    If focus_SHEET.Name = "staffnames" Then
        'skip over the staff list
        'do nothing
        MsgBox ("skip " & focus_SHEET.Name)
    ElseIf Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        'found name on the list
        'do nothing
        MsgBox ("found " & Range("C4"))
    Else:
        'did not find name on the list
        MsgBox ("unrecognized name: " & Range("C4"))

        'delete the tab
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        focus_SHEET.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next focus_SHEET
Set focus_SHEET = Nothing
Set Rng = Nothing

End Sub
```

You can also add more features that will automatically open the source of your staff names.  But this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: This is perfect. Also added in having each sheet formatted for printing and renaming sheet to the name in C4 if it's on the list. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

[Excel clear cells based on contents of a list in another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302891/excel-clear-cells-based-on-contents-of-a-list-in-another-sheet)

I beleive this should help you out. It's always worth searching for an answer online as chances are someone has already tried to do the exact thing you're trying to do :)

7's